# Data is showing only after I hot reload or refresh in flutter

Tags: flutter

In my database I have a user table where username, some marks are stored. I want to view that data in a table when user go to a particular page. So, when I go to that page at first the data(username and marks) doesn't show. But if I hot reload or use a button to refresh then the data shows properly. My question is how can I do that without hot reload or using a refresh button. Here is my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app/database/db_helper.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app/database/user.dart';

class ViewResult extends StatefulWidget {
 @override
 _ViewResult createState() => _ViewResult();
}

GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey();

class _ViewResult extends State<ViewResult> {
 String tempEmail;
 bool check = true;

 var dbHelper;
 var data = List<User>();

 @override
 void initState() {
   setState(() {
     dbHelper = DBHelper();
     resultData();
   });
   super.initState();
 }

 void resultData() {
     dbHelper.getUser().then((users) {
       for (User temp in users) {
         if (temp.type == "student") data.add(temp);
       }
     });
 }

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Scaffold(
     appBar: AppBar(
       centerTitle: true,
       title: Text("Result"),
     ),
     body: DataTable(
       columnSpacing: 22,
       columns: [
         DataColumn(label: Text("Username")),
         DataColumn(label: Text("Beginner")),
         DataColumn(label: Text("Intermediate")),
         DataColumn(label: Text("Advanced")),
       ],
       rows: data
           .map((user) => DataRow(cells: [
                 DataCell(Text(user.email)),
                 DataCell(Text(user.beginnerMark.toString())),
                 DataCell(Text(user.intermediateMark.toString())),
                 DataCell(Text(user.advancedMark.toString())),
               ]))
           .toList(),
     ),
     backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(130, 178, 220, 1),
   );
 }
}
```

Comment: You're missing a setState call in your getUser.then

Comment: sorry, can you please explain more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**TLDR:** Call `setState()` from inside `then()` if not, it will be executed before everything completes and have no effect at all.

```
getUser().then((response) {
   //Your stuff

   setState(() {}); //refresh
  });
```

Comment: This is al right but problem with this approach is , it is building the whole page again which causes performance issue . Try doing this with any state management library instead.

Comment: @Mdomerarafat To mitigate the performance issue, create another custom stateful widget and use this code inside of that to only call setState on the widget you need to refresh

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `setState` *after* you have loaded the data and your `resultData` functions is working with `then`, that is executed after the initial `setState` in the `initState` is finished.

```
@override
void initState() {
  // super.initState(); should be at the start of the method
  super.initState();
  dbHelper = DBHelper();
  resultData();
}

void resultData() {
  dbHelper.getUser().then((users) {
    for (User temp in users) {
      if (temp.type == "student") data.add(temp);
    }
    // since you have already added the results to data
    // setState can have an empty function body
    setState(() {});
  });
}
```

I prefer working with `async/await` instead of `then` so my solutions would be as follows:

```
Future<void> resultData() async {
  List<User> users = await dbHelper.getUser();
  setState(() {
    data = users.where((user) => user.type == "student");
  });
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You need  `setState(() {});`.
Add it near the end of `resultData` function:

```
void resultData() {
  dbHelper.getUser().then((users) {
     for (User temp in users) {
       if (temp.type == "student") data.add(temp);
     }
   setState(() {});
  });

}
```

See [`setState`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/setState.html) for more information.

Comment: The `setState()` has to be called from inside `then()`, otherwise it will be executed first and have no effect at all.